# Рухнул весь проект, ошибки npm

Tags: node.js, npm, babel

Перенес проект с работы домой. Дома при введении npm i вышла ошибка, что проекту требуется babel. В зависимости добавил строку "babel-loader": "8.1.0" - это помогло.

Когда вернулся на работу и сделал git pull, то рухнул весь проект. Не помогают удаления папки с модулями и локов, ни вышеупомянутого babel, ни клонирование проекта с репозитория. Понимаю, что могу дописать ключ --force, но хочется это всё дело "культурно" починить. Что конкретно с меня требуется? Ниже публикую весь package.json и лог ошибок.

```
    {
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@cypress/webpack-dev-server": "^1.4.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.18",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.15",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.2",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sass": "^1.35.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "test:cy": "cypress open",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.stories.*"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.8",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.14.5",
    "@cypress/react": "^5.9.2",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.3.7",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.3.7",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.3.7",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.3.7",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.2.0",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.3.7",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.9",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.8",
    "cypress": "^8.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0"
  }
}

$ npm i
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^=16.x || ^=17.x" from @cypress/react@5.9.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@cypress/react
npm ERR!     dev @cypress/react@"^5.9.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   30 more (react-dom, @storybook/addon-actions, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"15.x || 16.x || 16.4.0-alpha.0911da3" from @reach/router@1.3.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@storybook/api/node_modules/@reach/router
npm ERR!   @reach/router@"^1.3.4" from @storybook/api@6.3.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@storybook/api
npm ERR!     @storybook/api@"6.3.7" from @storybook/addon-actions@6.3.7
npm ERR!     node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions
npm ERR!       dev @storybook/addon-actions@"^6.3.7" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (@storybook/addon-essentials)
npm ERR!     10 more (@storybook/addon-essentials, @storybook/addons, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/user/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2021-08-23T05_57_35_443Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

стоит react@17.0.2  а пакеты требуют ниже

peer react@"15.x || 16.x || 16.4.0-alpha.0911da3" from @reach/router@1.3.4

сделать даунгрейд реакта, либо с пакетами разобарться

"react": "^17.0.2" в зависимостях 17 реакт стоит, запроси пониже и пересобери.